# How to define CSS for Custom Display Suite Layout

Tags: theming, display-suite

I have added a custom layout for Display Suite on Drupal 8. Everything is working except the CSS for the custom layout is not working.

This is my layout in my theme folder:

`mytheme.layouts.yml`

```
ds_3col_guide:
  label: Guide - Three column stacked 
  category: Display Suite
  class: '\Drupal\ds\Plugin\DsLayout'
  type: partial
  template: templates/ds/ds-3col-guide
  library: ds/ds_3col_guide
  icon: templates/ds/ds-3col-guide.png
  regions:
    header:
      label: Header
    left:
      label: Left
    middle:
      label: Middle
    right:
      label: Right
    footer:
      label: Footer
```

The CSS for this is located here: `templates/ds/ds-3col-guide.css`

1. Do I add the CSS reference to `mytheme.layouts.yml` or to `mytheme.libraries.yml`?
2. Would this be the right way to add it?

   ```
   css:
     theme:
       templates/ds/ds-3col-guide.css: {}
   ```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: i have crated created ds-2col-stacked-custom.html.twig (my_theme/ds_layouts/ds-2col-stacked) and wrote a layout with all css classes that i need, created mytheme.layouts.yml and declared my custom layout template. when i check webpage - template works, content is rendered where it should be, css classes are asigned BUT I have same BIG issue css rules are not working. css file is located: ds_layouts/ds-2col-stacked/ds-2col-stacked-custom.css

Comment: had same problem, check this [Creating Display Suite Custome Layout](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/266204/creating-display-suite-custome-layout)