# Creating a Display Suite Custom Layout

Tags: 8, theming, display-suite

I'm using Display Suite for my website and I want to add a couple layouts to Display Suite, to apply to some pages. I have checked out how to add custom layout to Drupal Suite with google, Stack Overflow and Drupal Answers. What I did:

- created a folder "ds_layouts" in my custom theme folder;
- created a folder for my custom layout "ds-2col-stacked-custom" in "ds_layouts" folder;
- created two files "ds-2col-stacked-custom.css" :

>

```
.ds-2col-stacked > .group-fhl {
  float: left; /* LTR */
      width: 70%;
}

.ds-2col-stacked > .group-fhr {
  float: right; /* LTR */
  width: 30%;
}

 .ds-2col-stacked > .group-left {
  float: left; /* LTR */
  width: 50%;
}

[dir="rtl"] .ds-2col-stacked > .group-left {
  float: right;
}

.ds-2col-stacked > .group-right {
  float: right; /* LTR */
  width: 50%;
}

[dir="rtl"] .ds-2col-stacked > .group-right {
  float: left;
}

.ds-2col-stacked > .group-footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

and "ds-2col-stacked-custom.html.twig" :

```
    <{{ outer_wrapper }}{{ attributes.addClass('ds-2col-stacked', 'clearfix') }}>

  {{ title_suffix.contextual_links }}


    <{{ fhl_wrapper }}{{ fhl_attributes.addClass('group-fhl') }}>
    {{ fhl }}
  </{{ fhl_wrapper }}>

  <{{ fhr_wrapper }}{{ fhr_attributes.addClass('group-fhr') }}>
    {{ fhr }}
  </{{ fhr_wrapper }}>


  <{{ header_wrapper }}{{ header_attributes.addClass('group-header') }}>
    {{ header }}
  </{{ header_wrapper }}>

  <{{ left_wrapper }}{{ left_attributes.addClass('group-left') }}>
    {{ left }}
  </{{ left_wrapper }}>

  <{{ right_wrapper }}{{ right_attributes.addClass('group-right') }}>
    {{ right }}
  </{{ right_wrapper }}>

  <{{ footer_wrapper }}{{ footer_attributes.addClass('group-footer') }}>
    {{ footer }}
  </{{ footer_wrapper }}>

</{{ outer_wrapper }}>
```

- in file "Mytheme.layout.yml", I added:

> 

```
ds_2col_stacked_custom:
  label: Two column stacked layout custom
  category: Display Suite
  class: '\Drupal\ds\Plugin\DsLayout'
  type: partial
  template: ds_layouts/ds-2col-stacked-custom/ds-2col-stacked-custom
  library: ds_2col_stacked_custom
  regions:
    fhl:
      label: fhl
    fhr:
      label: fhr
    header:
      label: Header
    left:
      label: Left
    right:
      label: Right
    footer:
          label: Footer
```

- in file "Mytheme.libraries.yml", I added:

> 

```
# DS.
ds_2col_stacked_custom:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      ds_layouts/ds-2col-stacked-custom/ds-2col-stacked-custom.css: {}
```

In Manage Display for page I see the option for my custom layout, and when I apply it, it's working (html tags and css classes are added to the page), but it does not apply any of my css for my layout. I think there is something wrong with the way I added css file to my custom layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re calling a library with dashes but it was defined with underscores. Update it to match the name.

You should be calling it via 'mytheme/library-name', so:

`library: mytheme/ds_2col_stacked_custom`

Comment: updated code (in question i updated it too) but still no luck. just to clear, i call css file via "library: ds_2col_stacked_custom" correct?

Comment: Clear the cache after any changes.

Comment: did that many times... nope... not working.

Comment: The code above still says `library: ds_2col_stacked_custom`

Comment: thanks. it worked when noticed and applied your comment :
You should be calling it via 'mytheme/library-name', so:
library: mytheme/ds_2col_stacked_custom